# Selenium right click sometimes double taps

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, right-click

I am doing a bot for the game minesweeper, in which I need to be able to rightclick tiles to warn for bombs. I've created a function for clicking on tiles with the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

def click(rad, kol, bomb = False):
    if int(rad) > 0 and int(kol) > 0:
        tile = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="{}_{}"]'.format(int(rad), int(kol)))

        if bomb == False:
            #Left click
            tile.click()
        else:
            #Right click
            actionChains.context_click(tile).perform()
            print("Right click")
```

But then when I call the function with the following code:

```
click(10, 10, True)
click(5, 5, True)
click(1,1,True)
```

Both the tiles with coordinates (10, 10) and (5,5) toggles on and off but only (10,10) turns on again after. Meanwhile the tile with the coordinate (1,1) does not toggle on and off but work properly.

I printed out every time the code for right click was run and it printet out "right click" 3 times as i should.

Edit: I have figured out that the problem is probably because actionChains remember it's previous actions and therefor click on all of the tiles again. But I can't figure out how delete the previous actions of the chain. The reset_actions() function doesn't seem to delete any action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that there was some bug reported with `reset_actions`
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6837
but it's closed and should be ok (I also had this problem on my machine)... Either try to update driver or I guess if it doesn't help then just assign `actionChains` one more time in `if` statement. That's the only quick solution that comes to my mind for now.

```
def click(rad, kol, bomb = False):
    if int(rad) > 0 and int(kol) > 0:
        tile = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="{}_{}"]'.format(int(rad), int(kol)))

        if bomb == False:
            #Left click
            tile.click()
        else:
            #Right click
            actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
            actionChains.context_click(tile).perform()
            print("Right click")
```